# backbone and listenTo and a strange border effect

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I define a backbone view

```
Views.BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
   viewState : new Backbone.Model(),
   initialize: function(){
       this.listenTo(this.viewState, "change:stateType", this.onAlertType)
  }
}
```

I have got GlobalView that extends BaseView, and that permits me to display and manage my ItemViews.
The ItemView extends as well the BaseView.

My problem is that if i change the viewState.stateType at the level of an ItemView :

```
MyItemView.viewState.set('stateType', 1)
```

the GlobalView is notify first about the change of the viewState property of the ItemView.

My GlobalView does not get any particular 'listenTo', the only 'listenTo' that I define is the one at the BaseView level.

Why the globalView is notified about the change on a viewState object define on ItemView ?
Does any one see what I am doing wrong ? Is that a known bug ?

Comment: is stateType a attribute of your model ? @yop

Answer (score 1):

When you define a property on a Backbone object (for example `View`) using `.extend`, the property is attached to the object's prototype. This means that the same property value is shared by all instances of that object.

This makes perfect sense on methods, because you don't want to create a new function instance for every method of each instance of your object. It's also relatively harmless on immutable value type properties, because the original value is not modified, and when you reassign the property with another value, a new property is created on the instance, and that hides the prototype property without modifying it:

```
var SomeView = BaseView.extend({
  foo:'foo'
});

var view1 = new SomeView();
var view2 = new SomeView();

view1.foo = 'bar';
console.log(view1.foo, view2.foo); // -> bar, foo
```

The problem arises when you set a property to a mutable object, such as an `Object`, `Array`, or similar. When you change that object without reassigning the property, this changes that property value on all instances.

In your case the `viewState` properties of all views are pointing to the same model instance, so:

```
var view1 = new SomeViewThatExtendsBaseView();
view1.viewState.set('stateType', 1);

var view2 = new SomeOtherViewThatAlsoExtendsBaseView();
console.log(view2.viewState.get('stateType')); // -> 1
```

To declare instance properties using Backbone, you should create them in the `initialize` method:

```
Views.BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.viewState = new Backbone.Model();
    this.listenTo(this.viewState, "change:stateType", this.onAlertType)
  }
}
```